# Knapsack algorithm dynamic programming .(incorrect output) here is what I have so far

Tags: python, algorithm, output

I wrote this code for dynamic programming implementation of the knapsack problem.

```
#B = maximum weight
#n = number of items
#p = list of weights
#a = list of values

#p[i] = weight with value a[i]



   def maximum_attractiveness(n, B, p, a):
     f = [i for i in range(n+1)]
     m = [f for i in range(B+1)]
     m[0] = [0 for i in range(len(m[0]))]
     for i in m:
      i[0] = 0
     print(m)
     for j in range(n):
      for w in range(B):
       if (p[j]) > (w):
        m[w][j] = m[w][j-1]
       else:
        m[w][j] = max(m[w][j-1],m[w-p[j]][j-1]+a[j])
    return m[B][n]
```

I get an incorrect output for this algorithm.  where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f = [i for i in range(n+1)]
m = [f for i in range(B+1)]
```

This uses the same array `f` for every position `m`, so for example if you change `m[1][k]`, you also change `m[i][k]` for every `i`. You probably meant to do

```
m = [[i for i in range(n+1)] for i in range(B+1)]
```

There might be some other bugs I think, so maybe you should print out the intermediate arrays at some points to check out where the results are not what you'd expect them to be.

**UPDATE:**

- Your initialization seems strange to me. I think it should be just  `m = [[0]*n for i in range(B+1)]` because you need a matrix of zeroes.
- it should be `for w in range(B+1)`
- you should not return `m[B][n]`, but `max(m[j][n] for j in range(B+1))`.

My attempt, which avoids the the matrix altogether and only uses a single array:

```
m = [0]*(B+1)
for j in range(n):
    for w in range(B,p[j]-1,-1):
        m[w] = max(m[w], m[w-p[j]] + a[j])
return max(m)
```

Comment: How about shortening `[i for i in range(x)]` to a simple `range(x)`?

Comment: @Alfe Since we need zeroes for every item, `[0]*x` is probably what OP needs. I didn't try to fix the "Pythonicity" though, just the code

Comment: @Alfe How do you know that OP isn't using python3? You cannot assign to a `range` object.

Comment: Right, @Hyperboreus, good point.  Seems to be Py3.  But the whole notion is moot now that Niklas changed the init to use zeros.